# In iOS, Can I check user say something or not?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, voice

I want to know is there a speech recognizer.
I just want to use it for check user speak something or not.
When users say something, the music stop.
And after user stop saying, the music restart.

How can I do that?

Comment: Yes there is an api for speech recognition. Take a look at this link.. http://www.devfright.com/quick-look-avspeechsynthesizer-class/

Comment: @XCode Monkey - AVSpeechSynthesizer converts text to speech, not the other way around.